# 'Invalid parameter "%Username%"' error when trying to grant permission by Icacls to current user

Tags: windows, icacls

From [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1470382) to question [Windows SSH: Permissions for 'private-key' are too open](https://superuser.com/q/1296024)
I knew about command

```
Icacls "C:\Users\XX\Path\To\File" /Grant:r "%Username%":"(R)"
```

but in my environment (windows 10) it does not work:

```
Invalid parameter "%Username%"
```

Why it happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

set var=whoami

Icacls "C:\Users\test" /Grant:r %var%:"(R)"

Answer (score -2):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls#examples) it is necessary to inform the user for the permission:

```
Icacls "C:\Users\XX\Path\To\File" /Grant:r takeshi:"(R)"
```

But the example above will only work for commands executed via `CMD`.
The message that is appearing means that the environment variable is empty. Why I can't tell you.

If you are using `PowerShell` you will have to change the `$Username` variable, in my example:

```
icacls.exe "C:\Temp\test.txt" /Grant:r "$Username":"(R)"
```

In `Powershell` I got the following response:

```
1 fichiers correctement traités ; échec du traitement de 0 fichiers
```

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer. I am sorry, but how suggested by you command differes from `Icacls "C:\Users\XX\Path\To\File" /Grant:r "%Username%":"(R)"` which I already executed?

Comment: By the example that is described in the documentation it is without the ""

Comment: The Question is about Dynamic Parameter not how to replace it with fixed value.